# big list need to place Quotes between strings

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a text file with a lot of strings now i want to put those strings into a array.

I need to set between the screen quites `""`,

Text file is saved as,

```html
String1
String2 
String3
```

This most be

```html
"String1", "String2, "String3"
```

Wat is the simplest way to do this in php/html/jquery ?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: "I need to set between the screen quites", what???

Comment: Easiest would be `$result = '"' . str_replace("\n", '", "', $input) . '"';`

Comment: How do i get the names automaticly from txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use [**file()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to create an array from the lines of the text file, and [**array_map()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to add the quotes:

```
$lines = file('myfile.txt');
$lines = array_map(function($x){return $x = '"'.$x.'"';}, $lines);
```

[**See this demo**](http://3v4l.org/6ijV5)

Comment: How do i get rid of output Array ( [0] => "String" i just want it to show "String"

Comment: @JohnSmith Hmmm, sounds like you need to learn some of the basics of php - variables, arrays, etc. Try `echo $lines[0]; echo $lines[1]; echo $lines[2]`... or better yet `foreach($lines as $line) echo $line;`... take a look at this: http://3v4l.org/BoYL0

Answer (score 0):

in php simply use `file()` function

```
<?php
$array = file('file.txt');
```

http://php.net//manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Ok but how do i get the "around the strings",

Answer (score 0):

To get your array you'd use this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => String1
    [1] => String2 
    [2] => String3 
)
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://eval.in/170482)

Now the full example would look like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);

$a = array();
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $a[] = "\"". trim($line) ."\"";
}
$string = implode(', ', $a);

print_r($a);
echo "String: " . $string;
```

That gives you the output of:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "String1"
    [1] => "String2"
    [2] => "String3"
)
String: "String1", "String2", "String3"
```

[**EXAMPLE**](https://eval.in/170493)

Comment: OP says the lines are stored in a text file - not a string. `explode()` won't work without first extracting from the file.

Comment: @MarkM Understood that. I presumed the OP knows how you get the file contents. Silly me!

Comment: Fair enough. Ya after getting files contents your method will work fine.